# How to create a new page from a clickable row table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a problem and i can't find any solution on the internet.
So i have a db with about 20 columns. I print from this db only 5 columns for a preview like this:

```
<?php
$host    = "localhost";
$user    = "user";
$pass    = "";
$db_name = "db_test";

//create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

//test if connection failed
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("connection failed: "
        . mysqli_connect_error()
        . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
        . ")");
}

//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id,first,sec,school,data FROM test");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
echo '<table class="data-table" border ="1">
        <tr class="data-heading">';  //initialize table tag
while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    echo '<td>' . $property->name . '</td>';  //get field name for header
    array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($all_property as $item) {
        echo '<td>' . $row[$item] . '</td>'; //get items using property value
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

After the table is print, I want when click is press to create a new page with all the records from the db for that specific id. I have search over the internet but i can't find any solution. Can anyone help me ?:) Thanks in advice.

Comment: You want the result on the same page or on the another page?

Comment: Another page :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve take the liberty of making a few changes to the structure of the code to make it simpler.

The solution is to embed something in an anchor (`a`) which has a query string linking to the next page. Something of this nature:

```
details.php?id=…
```

Anyway, here is a solution:

```
$thead=array();
$tbody=array();

//  Set Properties
    $all_property = array('id','first','sec','school','data');  //  ***
    //  Note: corrected an error which incorrectly imploded thead:
    $thead=sprintf('<tr>%s</tr>',implode('',$all_property));    //  implode & put into a proper row

//  Get Data
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tr=array();
        foreach ($all_property as $item) {
            //  Here is a solution: Make id clickable
                if($item=='id')
                    $tr[]=sprintf('<th><a href="details.php?id=%s">%s</a></th>',$item,$item);
                else $tr[]=sprintf('<td>%s</td>');
        }
        $tbody[]=sprintf('<tr>%s</tr>',implode('',$tr));
    }
```

And in the HTML after the PHP block:

```
<table class="">
    <thead>
        <?php print $thead; ?>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php print $tbody; ?>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Note the following points:

- You shouldn’t put the logic into the HTML part of the document. Here I have just put the data into some variables to be output when the time comes. It’s cleaner and easier to maintain.
- The recommend way to push onto an array is to use the `$array[]=…` notation.
- I’m not sure why you are reading the column names if you already know that for your SQL query. However, I’ve left it that way.
- I’ve also include suitable `th` elements and table sections.

That might work …

Comment: Hey Manngo thank you for your replay, but i receive tow errors from mysqli_fetch_field

Comment: @fhffhf Ah, that would be because `mysqli_fetch_field` doesn’t, in fact, exist. There used to be `mysql_fetch_field` (without the `i`), but that’s been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed altogether in PHP 7. I have replaced the line with a hard-coded array (`***` above). Personally I use PDO for database work as it’s more scaleable.

Comment: I have try to make the changes but also give me some errors like :  Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given , Undefined variable: thead , Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed, Notice: Undefined variable: tbody

Comment: @fhffhf is it `mysql_query` or `mysqli_query` (ie is there an `i` in the function name)? php.net shows how the parameters are different. You should _not_ use the old functions. I can’t explain here the `tbody` error is coming from, but I did find an error in my code regarding `thead` which I have fixed (I imploded the wrong variable). The `tbody` error might be a result of the previous code failing.

Comment: Just let me shoe you how looks my code until now, maybe i have done some mistakes.

Comment: Just another quick question. details.php what should contain more exactly?

Comment: @fhffhf That’s a non-trivial request. Roughly, it is something along these lines: `$id=intval(@$_GET['id']); if($id) …;`. Use the `$id` variable to fetch the full row. Remember that since you are now using received data, _you should always use PREPARED statements_ to protect yourself from SQL injection. If you’re not sure about that, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can play with hide() and show() using Jquery to achieve this. Initially you load all columns from the db and next you hide using some jquery functions. So on click the table again call jquery show method to display remaining columns

Answer (score 0):

For that, use jQuery or other javascript supports. Basically redirect user to another page with "page?id=1". then extract id from url then use jQuery or js to load the corresponding values.

create a new page with empty form fields. then on load, get url parameter and use javascript to fill the fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$host    = "localhost";
$user    = "user";
$pass    = "";
$db_name = "db";

//create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

//test if connection failed
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("connection failed: "
        . mysqli_connect_error()
        . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno()
        . ")");
}

//get results from database
echo '<table class="data-table" border ="1">
        <tr class="data-heading">';  //initialize table tag
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id,firstname,lastname,email FROM test");
//  Set Properties
$all_property = array('id','first','sec','school','data');  //  ***
$thead=sprintf('<tr>%s</tr>',implode('',$thead));   //  implode & put into a proper row

//  Get Data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tr=array();
        foreach ($all_property as $item) {
            //  Here is a solution: Make id clickable
                if($item=='id')
                    $tr[]=sprintf('<th><a href="details.php?id=%s">%s</a></th>',$item,$item);
                else $tr[]=sprintf('<td>%s</td>');
        }
        $tbody[]=sprintf('<tr>%s</tr>',implode('',$tr));
    }
?>

<table class="data-heading">
    <thead>
        <?php print $thead; ?>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php print $tbody; ?>
    <tbody>
```